# Class has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am incredibly new to working with GUIs (and Python in general) so I decided to attempt the hardest thing I could possibly think of in order to learn the code better.  I am designing a game from scratch by myself (it's pretty much a Pokemon rip-off but I have no intention of making any of it publicly available and everything is pulled from open-sources such as bulbapedia).  I'm not having too much trouble with the coreEngine code yet; however, I tried to take a break from the Engine and work on the GUI for a bit.  I decided to use Tkinter, mostly because I don't know anything about GUIs or any other GUI modules in python, and have run into a problem just a few lines in the script.  My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
import battleEngine
import openingSequence
from classes import Pokemon
from classes import movesList

def donothing():
    print "Doesn't do anything."

class gameWindow(Frame):
    def displayMenu(self):
        gameMenu = Menu
        fileMenu = Menu(gameMenu, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New Game", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Load Game", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save Game", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save Game as...", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit())

    def __init__(self):
        self.displayMenu()

inGame = gameWindow()

inGame.mainloop()
```

Whenever I call this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/path/to/file/pokemonGui.py", line 26, in <module>
        inGame = gameWindow()
    File "C:/path/to/file/pokemonGui.py", line 24, in __init__
        self.displayMenu()
    File "C:/path/to/file/pokemonGui.py", line 15, in displayMenu
        fileMenu = Menu(gameMenu, tearoff=0)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2642, in __init__
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'menu', cnf, kw)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2027, in __init__
        BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2005, in _setup
        self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: class Menu has no attribute 'tk'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm confident this is simply my lack of understanding with Tkinter and GUIs and Menus; however, I can't seem to figure this out... I'm just trying to create a basic drop-down menu to go across the top of the screen (File, Edit, View, Help, etc...) but I have no clue how to do that...

Comment: `gameMenu = Menu` should be `gameMenu = Menu()`. otherwise gameMenu is the class itself and not an instance thereof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import battleEngine
import openingSequence
from classes import Pokemon
from classes import movesList

def donothing():
    print "Doesn't do anything."

class gameWindow(Frame):
    def displayMenu(self):
        gameMenu = Menu()
        fileMenu = Menu(gameMenu, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New Game", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Load Game", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save Game", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save Game as...", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit())

    def __init__(self):
        self.displayMenu()

inGame = gameWindow()

inGame.mainloop()
```

The only difference being in line 12(including empty lines) where gameMenu should = Menu().

Comment: This cleared the error code; however, It doesn't render any output.  I get a "Process finished with exit code 0"  I thought this would render just a basic window with a menu on the top (thought it would only say "File" right now)

Comment: That's because the last call of add_command has exit with brackets so, just remove the brackets